# Entity Framework - database first - PascalCase

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am starting a new project using Asp.NET MVC and I intend to reuse a SQL Server database that has more than 100 tables.  I would like to use entity framework in this new project, but, this database has the fields and tables name as following:

- Tables: product, product_category
- Fields: id, description,
  max_price.. (most part of them are lower case, separated by
  underscore)

However, when I try to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (edmx file) the generated classes and proprieties are in the same way (lower case, separated by underscore).

I would like:

- Classes: Product, ProductCategory
- Proprieties: Id, Description, MaxPrice

Ages ago, I used the Devart mapper to map my entities and it solved this problem out but I do not want to it anymore. I just would like to know if are there any tool to resolve this situation, templates t4 or another tool like Devart?

What are you using to map your database (database first)?

PS: I really want to use EF. And I would appreciate a suggestion where could be very straight forward to update my model when my database changes.

Thank you!

Comment: You have 2 options: 1) go into the mapping editor (.edmx file) and change them manually, 2) change your database column names. I know, both options are not optimal. However, it might not be a big deal to keep the column names the same. It will only be seen in the code, not in the UI.

Comment: You can customize the T4 templates to correct the names of the mapped entities. It depends on whic T4 template you're using to reverse engineer your DB